# Difference between Mac and Linux iconv UTF16 to UTF8

Tags: macos, utf-8, utf-16

I'm sure this is one of those weird differences between Linux and the Mac.  On Linux I can convert a UTF-16 encoded file to a UTF-8 encoded one by doing:

```
 iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 /tmp/geocache_visits.txt > /tmp/converted_geocache_visits.txt
```

However when I do it on my MacBook Pro, I end up with weird characters with some Chinese or Japanese interspersed.  I've tried some other formats (like ascii and UTF-8-MAC) which iconv --list claims to be ok, but it errors out.

How can I convert it into something I can read?

Comment: First, try using `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16BE` instead of just `UTF-16`. If that doesn't help, show the output from running `hexdump -C -n 20 /tmp/geocache_visits.txt /tmp/converted_geocache_visits.txt` after the `iconv` command you ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to use UTF-16LE worked like a charm.  Thanks!